# Python data fitting using curve_fit

Tags: python, data-analysis

(This task uses the jupyter notebook system)

This is not

Fit the Higgs mass - given a fitter(xvalues, data, init) function below, write a function fitfunc(...) that describes the combined background and signal model to fit the data. Create two pictures:

(a) plot the data with cross markers ('+' symbol) and the best fit curve as red line on the first plot and

(b) draw the residuals with cross markers on the second plot where residuals are defined as the difference between best fit model and pure background model, see below.

The fit function is composed of a background model with 3 parameters

()= * exp(1(−105.5)+2(−105.5)^2)

The signal is added to the background and its model is

()=/(√(2)) * exp(−(−)^2/(2^2))

The equations are not an issue, it is easy to put them into code, as I have done below:

```
# YOUR CODE HERE
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def fitfunc(m, mu, sigma, R, A, b1, b2):
    tb1 = b1 * (m - 105.5)
    tb2 = b2 * ((m-105.5)**2)
    b = A * np.exp(tb1 + tb2)
    ts1 = R / (sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi))
    ts2 = -(((m - mu)**2) / (2 * (sigma**2)))
    s = ts1 * np.exp(ts2)
    tot = b + s
    return tot
#


def fitter(xval, yval, initial):
    ''' function to fit the given data using a 'fitfunc' TBD. 
        The curve_fit function is called. Only the best fit values 
        are returned to be utilized in a main script.
    '''
    best, _ = curve_fit(fitfunc, xval, yval, p0=initial)
    return best

# Use functions with script below for plotting parts (a) and (b)
```

The fitter method was already provided, so I don't think it is to be changed.

This is my code for plotting the results:

```
# start value parameter definitions, see equations for s(m) and b(m).
# init[0] = mu
# init[1] = sigma
# init[2] = R
# init[3] = A
# init[4] = b1
# init[5] = b2
init = (125.8, 1.4, 470.0, 5000.0, -0.04, -1.5e-4)
xvalues = np.arange(start=105.5, stop=160.5, step=1)
data = np.array([4780, 4440, 4205, 4150, 3920, 3890, 3590, 3460, 3300, 3200, 3000, 
                 2950, 2830, 2700, 2620, 2610, 2510, 2280, 2330, 2345, 2300, 2190, 
                 2080, 1990, 1840, 1830, 1730, 1680, 1620, 1600, 1540, 1505, 1450, 
                 1410, 1380, 1380, 1250, 1230, 1220, 1110, 1110, 1080, 1055, 1050, 
                 940, 920, 950, 880, 870, 850, 800, 820, 810, 770, 760])
# YOUR CODE HERE
def main():
    arr = np.ndarray(init)
    fitt = fitfunc(xvalues, init[0], init[1], init[2], init[3], init[4], init[5])
    def plota(xval, yval):
        fig = plt.figure()
        axis1 = fig.add_axes([0.12, 0.1, 0.85, 0.85])
        axis1.plot(xval, yval, marker="+", color="red")
        axis1.set_title("Combined", size=12)
        axis1.set_xlabel("Mass [GeV]", size=12)
        plt.show()
        return
    plota(xvalues, fitt)
    plota(xvalues, fitter(xvalues, fitt, arr))
main()
```

In this second block, my code starts after the "#YOUR CODE HERE", the rest was already provided.

At the end, the first call of plota() is a curve of the data points found and the second call is my attempt at doing a "best fit curve" as asked by (a). The first call plots just fine, but is not what the question is asking for. This gives a type error: "'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer". I tried rounding these to integers as well, and I get this error instead: "fitfunc() missing 6 required positional arguments: 'mu', 'sigma', 'R', 'A', 'b1', and 'b2'". I think I am on the right lines with the second call, but I don't know what the third parameter of the fitter method is supposed to be. Looking through the notes I have been provided, it says that it is supposed to be some sort of initial guess but I don't know what this would have to be.

As for part (b), I am not sure how I would get the residuals, I think I can just iterate through the "best" array returned from the fitter method and calculate b(m) values separately and subtract, but I am unsure of the wording of the question.

Thank you for any help.

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-30fd8d6062a3> in <module>
     27     plota(xvalues, fitt)
     28     plota(xvalues, fitter(xvalues, fitt, arr))
---> 29 main()
     30 

<ipython-input-2-30fd8d6062a3> in main()
     26         return
     27     plota(xvalues, fitt)
---> 28     plota(xvalues, fitter(xvalues, fitt, arr))
     29 main()
     30 

<ipython-input-1-ac8e97799a28> in fitter(xval, yval, initial)
     22         are returned to be utilized in a main script.
     23     '''
---> 24     best, _ = curve_fit(fitfunc, xval, yval, p0=initial)
     25     return best
     26 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0, sigma, absolute_sigma, check_finite, bounds, method, jac, **kwargs)
    750         # Remove full_output from kwargs, otherwise we're passing it in twice.
    751         return_full = kwargs.pop('full_output', False)
--> 752         res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
    753         popt, pcov, infodict, errmsg, ier = res
    754         cost = np.sum(infodict['fvec'] ** 2)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun, full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    381     if not isinstance(args, tuple):
    382         args = (args,)
--> 383     shape, dtype = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)
    384     m = shape[0]
    385 

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs, output_shape)
     24 def _check_func(checker, argname, thefunc, x0, args, numinputs,
     25                 output_shape=None):
---> 26     res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
     27     if (output_shape is not None) and (shape(res) != output_shape):
     28         if (output_shape[0] != 1):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in func_wrapped(params)
    456     if transform is None:
    457         def func_wrapped(params):
--> 458             return func(xdata, *params) - ydata
    459     elif transform.ndim == 1:
    460         def func_wrapped(params):

TypeError: fitfunc() missing 6 required positional arguments: 'mu', 'sigma', 'R', 'A', 'b1', and 'b2'
```

Comment: Try using // for integer division and not have floats.

Comment: I  have amended the question, this error isn't the main issue, it is that I don't know what needs to be used as a parameter for the call of the fitter method, and I'm not sure if I'm using it correctly.

Comment: I would look at your curve_fit() function and see what p0 is, that is the 3rd input to your fitter method, it might just be the 0th element in some of your data. Without more info it seems difficult to help.  What line is the fitfunc error on? It looks like you are passing in values just fine.

Comment: I have added the error report but I don't really know what is going on, I think p0 is supposed to be an array of "initial guesses" but I don't know what these would be.

Comment: Well when i modify your init array to be `init = (126, 2, 470, 5000, 1, 5)` to quck fix issues with negative values and such, toggling overcommit_memory, I get a runtimeWarning and no errors about input arguments.

Comment: What are you using for a gui for drawing the plots?

Comment: I am supposed to leave the init array as it is, but I will create another one with the values you have suggested, I am not sure what overcommit_memory is

Comment: this is using the jupyter notebook system it displays graphs etc by itself

Comment: nothing to worry about, i just fixed the init array so it wouldn't error for me. Use those values if you have to.

Comment: I made another array with the values in your init and now there is no error message but it is not displaying any graph either

Comment: Ok so the docs for curve_fit are here https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're close but for two things:

1. values for `b1` and `b2` > 0 can lead to Infinities in the exponents
2. the return value from `curve_fit` are the best parameter values, not the best fit.  You'll have to calculate that yourself.

You also probably want to fit the data array, right?  I think this might be what you're looking for

```
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def fitfunc(m, mu, sigma, R, A, b1, b2):
    """comment about Higgs mass here"""
    tb1 = b1 * (m - 105.5)
    tb2 = b2 * ((m-105.5)**2)
    b = A * np.exp(tb1 + tb2)
    ts1 = R / (sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi))
    ts2 = -(((m - mu)**2) / (2 * (sigma**2)))
    s = ts1 * np.exp(ts2)
    tot = b + s
    return tot

xvalues = np.arange(start=105.5, stop=160.5, step=1)
data = np.array([4780, 4440, 4205, 4150, 3920, 3890, 3590, 3460, 3300, 3200, 3000,
                 2950, 2830, 2700, 2620, 2610, 2510, 2280, 2330, 2345, 2300, 2190,
                 2080, 1990, 1840, 1830, 1730, 1680, 1620, 1600, 1540, 1505, 1450,
                 1410, 1380, 1380, 1250, 1230, 1220, 1110, 1110, 1080, 1055, 1050,
                 940, 920, 950, 880, 870, 850, 800, 820, 810, 770, 760])

# start value parameter definitions, see equations for s(m) and b(m).
# init[0] = mu
# init[1] = sigma
# init[2] = R
# init[3] = A
# init[4] = b1
# init[5] = b2

init = np.array([125.8, 2, 470, 5000., -0.05, -0.001])

init_fit = fitfunc(xvalues, *init)

best, _ = curve_fit(fitfunc, xvalues, data, p0=init)
print(best)

best_fit = fitfunc(xvalues, *best)

plt.plot(xvalues, data, color='red', marker='+', label='data')
plt.plot(xvalues, init_fit, color='black',  label='init')
plt.plot(xvalues, best_fit, color='blue',  label='fit')
plt.gca().set_title("Combined", size=12)
plt.gca().set_xlabel("Mass [GeV]", size=12)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

If you'll allow, I'd also suggest using `lmfit` (http://lmfit.github.io/lmfit-py/) (disclosure: I am one of the authors) for this. Using this library, the code above with `curve_fit` would transform to

```
import lmfit
h_model = Model(fitfunc)
params = h_model.make_params(mu=125.8, sigma=2, R=470, 
                             A=5000, b1=-0.05, b2=-0.001)
result = h_model.fit(data, params, m=xvalues)

print(result.fit_report())

plt.plot(xvalues, data, color='red', marker='+', label='data')
plt.plot(xvalues, result.init_fit, color='black',  label='init')
plt.plot(xvalues, result.best_fit, color='blue',  label='fit')
plt.gca().set_title("Combined", size=12)
plt.gca().set_xlabel("Mass [GeV]", size=12)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Note here that with lmfit, Parameters are *named* using your function arguments.  In `lmfit` all parameters can have bounds, so you could do something like

```
params['b1'].max = 0.0
```

to ensure that `b1` stays negative  You can also fix any of the parameter values.  And there are many other features.

The printed report for this fit would include estimates of uncertainties and correlations as well as fit statistics:

```
[[Model]]
    Model(fitfunc)
[[Fit Statistics]]
    # fitting method   = leastsq
    # function evals   = 100
    # data points      = 55
    # variables        = 6
    chi-square         = 106329.424
    reduced chi-square = 2169.98824
    Akaike info crit   = 428.183028
    Bayesian info crit = 440.227027
[[Variables]]
    mu:     125.940465 +/- 0.34609625 (0.27%) (init = 125.8)
    sigma:  1.52638256 +/- 0.37354633 (24.47%) (init = 2)
    R:      677.016219 +/- 163.585050 (24.16%) (init = 470)
    A:      4660.71073 +/- 24.3437093 (0.52%) (init = 5000)
    b1:    -0.04279037 +/- 7.7658e-04 (1.81%) (init = -0.05)
    b2:     1.7476e-04 +/- 1.7587e-05 (10.06%) (init = -0.001)
[[Correlations]] (unreported correlations are < 0.100)
    C(b1, b2)    = -0.952
    C(A, b1)     = -0.775
    C(sigma, R)  =  0.655
    C(A, b2)     =  0.650
    C(R, b1)     = -0.492
    C(R, b2)     =  0.445
    C(sigma, b1) = -0.317
    C(sigma, b2) =  0.287
    C(R, A)      =  0.230
    C(sigma, A)  =  0.146
```

and the plot would look something like
[image]

Comment: Thank you for the time and effort you put into this, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code to run, so your init array has changed for me here.

```
"""."""
# YOUR CODE HERE
import math
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit


def fitfunc(m, mu, sigma, R, A, b1, b2):
    """."""
    tb1 = b1 * (m - 105.5)
    tb2 = b2 * ((m-105.5)**2)
    b = A * np.exp(tb1 + tb2)
    ts1 = R / (sigma * np.sqrt(2 * np.pi))
    ts2 = -(((m - mu)**2) / (2 * (sigma**2)))
    s = ts1 * np.exp(ts2)
    tot = b + s
    return tot


def fitter(xval, yval, initial):
    """
    Function to fit the given data using a 'fitfunc' TBD.

    The curve_fit function is called. Only the best fit values
    are returned to be utilized in a main script.
    """
    best, _ = curve_fit(fitfunc, xval, yval, p0=initial)
    return best

# Use functions with script below for plotting parts (a) and (b)


# start value parameter definitions, see equations for s(m) and b(m).
# init[0] = mu
# init[1] = sigma
# init[2] = R
# init[3] = A
# init[4] = b1
# init[5] = b2
init = (126, 2, 470, 5000, 1, 5)
xvalues = np.arange(start=105.5, stop=160.5, step=1)
data = np.array([4780, 4440, 4205, 4150, 3920, 3890, 3590, 3460, 3300, 3200, 3000,
                 2950, 2830, 2700, 2620, 2610, 2510, 2280, 2330, 2345, 2300, 2190,


    2080, 1990, 1840, 1830, 1730, 1680, 1620, 1600, 1540, 1505, 1450,
             1410, 1380, 1380, 1250, 1230, 1220, 1110, 1110, 1080, 1055, 1050,
             940, 920, 950, 880, 870, 850, 800, 820, 810, 770, 760])


def main():
"""."""
arr = np.ndarray(init)
fitt = fitfunc(xvalues, init[0], init[1], init[2], init[3], init[4], init[5])

def plota(xval, yval):
    fig = plt.figure()
    axis1 = fig.add_axes([0.12, 0.1, 0.85, 0.85])
    axis1.plot(xval, yval, marker="+", color="red")
    axis1.set_title("Combined", size=12)
    axis1.set_xlabel("Mass [GeV]", size=12)
    plt.show()
    return
plota(xvalues, fitt)
plota(xvalues, fitter(xvalues, fitt, arr))


main()
```

Note the indentation on main is off by 1 tab/space grouping.

Comment: not sure why the indentation is like that, it just gives me errors, otherwise it compiles but it doesn't draw any graph